# Get content result from HttpRequestMessage?

Tags: c#, httpclient

I have the following code:

```
var client = new HttpClient()
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://myhost:myport/"),
};
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 

var uri = @"myurl";

var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myobject);
string responseResult = string.Empty;

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, uri);
request.Content = new StringContent(s, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

client.SendAsync(request)
      .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
      {
           responseResult = responseTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
      });

txtLog.Text = responseResult;
```

The above request should return a string result, however, the result is empty. Would am I missing?

Comment: The ContinueWith ensures the method it contains will be executed after the AsyncCall, but it's still asynchronous. Which means your assignation to "txtLog.Text" might happen before the "ContinueWith" is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the result until after the continuation has run, so move the assignment to the `Text` property into the continuation:

```
client.SendAsync(request)
    .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
    {
        responseResult = responseTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        txtLog.Text = responseResult;
    });
```

An additional complication is that the `Text` property only wants to be set on the UI thread:

```
client.SendAsync(request)
    .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
    {
        responseResult = responseTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => txtLog.Text = responseResult);
    });
```

**EDIT**

Await/async is usually easier to work with; you can replace the above with this:

```
var message = await client.SendAsync(request);
responseResult = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
txtLog.Text = responseResult;
```